# Find distance from point to nearest polygon in Python

Tags: python, polygon, distance, point, geopandas

I have a geodataframe with coordinates of locations and another with polygons that denote flood areas. For each location point, I need to find the distance to the nearest flood area but I'm unable to do so. This is what the data looks like and what I have done.

```
points.head()

    Latitude    Longitude   geometry
0   29.873542   -95.300914  POINT (-95.30091 29.87354)
1   29.689952   -95.528468  POINT (-95.52847 29.68995)
2   29.789688   -95.090620  POINT (-95.09062 29.78969)
3   29.559194   -95.145382  POINT (-95.14538 29.55919)
4   29.817562   -95.720350  POINT (-95.72035 29.81756)


shape3.head()

    geometry    flood2
2   POLYGON ((-96.17839 29.80032, -96.17845 29.800...   AV
3   POLYGON ((-96.14694 30.05772, -96.14695 30.057...   AV
5   POLYGON ((-96.09303 29.65069, -96.09323 29.650...   AV
8   POLYGON ((-96.46769 29.86118, -96.46754 29.861...   AV
10  POLYGON ((-96.42751 29.84184, -96.42716 29.841...   AV
```

EDIT: Without the truncation, the polygons look like this

```
    geometry    flood2
2   POLYGON ((-96.17839 29.80032, -96.17845 29.80025, -96.17855 29.80013, -96.17870 29.79998, -96.17882 29.79982, -96.17886 29.79977, -96.17908 29.79942, -96.17919 29.79922, -96.17931 29.79906, -96.17944 29.79890, -96.17948 29.79883, -96.17964 29.79866, -96.17969 29.79868, -96.17977 29.79869, -96.17987 29.79878, -96.17994 29.79879, -96.18019 29.79877, -96.18042 29.79870, -96.18063 29.79861, -96.18071 29.79858, -96.18073 29.79858, -96.18075 29.79857, -96.18080 29.79855, -96.18085 29.79856, -96.18085 29.79860, -96.18080 29.79864, -96.18077 29.79867, -96.18075 29.79868, -96.18065 29.79873, -96.18044 29.79883, -96.18031 29.79890, -96.18017 29.79899, -96.18000 29.79913, -96.17977 29.79938, -96.17967 29.79948, -96.17949 29.79973, -96.17918 29.79998, -96.17902 29.80014, -96.17895 29.80023, -96.17891 29.80031, -96.17887 29.80039, -96.17884 29.80045, -96.17839 29.80032))  AV
3   POLYGON ((-96.14694 30.05772, -96.14695 30.05772, -96.14697 30.05770, -96.14702 30.05765, -96.14707 30.05762, -96.14713 30.05756, -96.14720 30.05750, -96.14721 30.05749, -96.14733 30.05739, -96.14756 30.05711, -96.14768 30.05692, -96.14775 30.05667, -96.14784 30.05621, -96.14786 30.05615, -96.14787 30.05599, -96.14769 30.05600, -96.14764 30.05598, -96.14761 30.05596, -96.14758 30.05589, -96.14757 30.05576, -96.14761 30.05559, -96.14763 30.05547, -96.14761 30.05517, -96.14755 30.05503, -96.14740 30.05493, -96.14728 30.05481, -96.14724 30.05468, -96.14711 30.05459, -96.14704 30.05451, -96.14704 30.05435, -96.14703 30.05434, -96.14696 30.05425, -96.14689 30.05416, -96.14676 30.05410, -96.14668 30.05403, -96.14665 30.05400, -96.14642 30.05388, -96.14618 30.05374, -96.14590 30.05360, -96.14574 30.05347, -96.14562 30.05327, -96.14561 30.05323, -96.14563 30.05324, -96.14575 30.05332, -96.14580 30.05338, -96.14582 30.05340, -96.14600 30.05348, -96.14618 30.05351, -96.14632 30.05354, -96.14649 30.05357, -96.14656 30.05359, -96.14668 30.05362, -96.14685 30.05366, -96.14703 30.05368, -96.14726 30.05372, -96.14734 30.05372, -96.14753 30.05378, -96.14761 30.05374, -96.14768 30.05361, -96.14764 30.05345, -96.14750 30.05325, -96.14745 30.05292, -96.14746 30.05281, -96.14744 30.05273, -96.14738 30.05265, -96.14687 30.05239, -96.14678 30.05231, -96.14674 30.05224, -96.14680 30.05220, -96.14697 30.05220, -96.14720 30.05225, -96.14748 30.05240, -96.14761 30.05242, -96.14773 30.05238, -96.14790 30.05223, -96.14796 30.05207, -96.14799 30.05190, -96.14826 30.05164, -96.14840 30.05157, -96.14845 30.05161, -96.14844 30.05170, -96.14828 30.05196, -96.14830 30.05203, -96.14840 30.05216, -96.14839 30.05224, -96.14822 30.05239, -96.14799 30.05267, -96.14795 30.05281, -96.14802 30.05318, -96.14812 30.05330, -96.14822 30.05333, -96.14836 30.05318, -96.14852 30.05307, -96.14865 30.05306, -96.14868 30.05316, -96.14866 30.05328, -96.14854 30.05357, -96.14855 30.05370, -96.14849 30.05382, -96.14832 30.05411, -96.14832 30.05420, -96.14836 30.05434, -96.14845 30.05450, -96.14877 30.05484, -96.14885 30.05498, -96.14885 30.05509, -96.14884 30.05521, -96.14884 30.05546, -96.14882 30.05558, -96.14882 30.05574, -96.14882 30.05577, -96.14880 30.05581, -96.14873 30.05585, -96.14863 30.05588, -96.14863 30.05589, -96.14862 30.05606, -96.14868 30.05615, -96.14877 30.05621, -96.14915 30.05622, -96.14950 30.05613, -96.14967 30.05614, -96.14962 30.05623, -96.14947 30.05641, -96.14936 30.05651, -96.14931 30.05657, -96.14919 30.05666, -96.14912 30.05672, -96.14905 30.05677, -96.14898 30.05683, -96.14895 30.05703, -96.14895 30.05732, -96.14904 30.05737, -96.14912 30.05745, -96.14918 30.05757, -96.14915 30.05762, -96.14905 30.05769, -96.14893 30.05772, -96.14879 30.05776, -96.14862 30.05781, -96.14847 30.05798, -96.14843 30.05811, -96.14843 30.05827, -96.14847 30.05847, -96.14847 30.05858, -96.14866 30.05882, -96.14866 30.05883, -96.14872 30.05890, -96.14874 30.05893, -96.14876 30.05898, -96.14878 30.05902, -96.14879 30.05906, -96.14879 30.05908, -96.14879 30.05913, -96.14879 30.05915, -96.14879 30.05915, -96.14878 30.05916, -96.14877 30.05921, -96.14874 30.05926, -96.14871 30.05929, -96.14871 30.05930, -96.14848 30.05910, -96.14817 30.05882, -96.14711 30.05787, -96.14698 30.05776, -96.14694 30.05772))  AV
5   POLYGON ((-96.09303 29.65069, -96.09323 29.65046, -96.09334 29.65036, -96.09360 29.65013, -96.09420 29.64981, -96.09474 29.64954, -96.09494 29.64951, -96.09509 29.64951, -96.09528 29.64951, -96.09548 29.64945, -96.09580 29.64928, -96.09603 29.64921, -96.09622 29.64903, -96.09642 29.64895, -96.09665 29.64900, -96.09690 29.64905, -96.09732 29.64888, -96.09756 29.64882, -96.09777 29.64881, -96.09795 29.64892, -96.09789 29.64900, -96.09775 29.64901, -96.09749 29.64907, -96.09720 29.64922, -96.09692 29.64936, -96.09656 29.64935, -96.09632 29.64937, -96.09600 29.64959, -96.09565 29.64981, -96.09543 29.64985, -96.09522 29.64999, -96.09503 29.64999, -96.09473 29.65015, -96.09449 29.65029, -96.09428 29.65037, -96.09392 29.65061, -96.09363 29.65075, -96.09343 29.65086, -96.09337 29.65092, -96.09327 29.65113, -96.09303 29.65069))  AV
8   POLYGON ((-96.46769 29.86118, -96.46754 29.86110, -96.46706 29.86111, -96.46687 29.86117, -96.46670 29.86131, -96.46666 29.86140, -96.46663 29.86164, -96.46649 29.86163, -96.46636 29.86158, -96.46603 29.86136, -96.46583 29.86125, -96.46555 29.86116, -96.46546 29.86114, -96.46544 29.86120, -96.46540 29.86123, -96.46530 29.86119, -96.46517 29.86115, -96.46502 29.86109, -96.46497 29.86103, -96.46497 29.86097, -96.46459 29.86073, -96.46414 29.86051, -96.46391 29.86031, -96.46384 29.86022, -96.46376 29.86007, -96.46372 29.85991, -96.46372 29.85978, -96.46373 29.85947, -96.46367 29.85938, -96.46351 29.85921, -96.46333 29.85900, -96.46324 29.85895, -96.46298 29.85886, -96.46280 29.85875, -96.46268 29.85862, -96.46256 29.85838, -96.46249 29.85835, -96.46229 29.85840, -96.46221 29.85837, -96.46205 29.85832, -96.46198 29.85831, -96.46185 29.85833, -96.46171 29.85842, -96.46152 29.85842, -96.46134 29.85832, -96.46116 29.85830, -96.46112 29.85823, -96.46117 29.85815, -96.46119 29.85814, -96.46120 29.85812, -96.46129 29.85805, -96.46141 29.85799, -96.46151 29.85796, -96.46157 29.85794, -96.46163 29.85791, -96.46173 29.85786, -96.46178 29.85780, -96.46178 29.85776, -96.46170 29.85757, -96.46166 29.85750, -96.46144 29.85727, -96.46124 29.85708, -96.46108 29.85694, -96.46090 29.85675, -96.46081 29.85657, -96.46077 29.85640, -96.46075 29.85620, -96.46071 29.85606, -96.46062 29.85592, -96.46043 29.85572, -96.46030 29.85552, -96.46025 29.85547, -96.46016 29.85541, -96.46001 29.85538, -96.45984 29.85541, -96.45943 29.85551, -96.45901 29.85553, -96.45886 29.85556, -96.45848 29.85567, -96.45826 29.85577, -96.45800 29.85589, -96.45784 29.85594, -96.45770 29.85594, -96.45745 29.85588, -96.45732 29.85583, -96.45708 29.85575, -96.45681 29.85574, -96.45655 29.85576, -96.45622 29.85570, -96.45599 29.85572, -96.45586 29.85575, -96.45579 29.85578, -96.45561 29.85592, -96.45551 29.85604, -96.45541 29.85617, -96.45526 29.85639, -96.45513 29.85652, -96.45500 29.85660, -96.45491 29.85664, -96.45481 29.85667, -96.45459 29.85669, -96.45403 29.85667, -96.45384 29.85662, -96.45356 29.85652, -96.45341 29.85654, -96.45332 29.85657, -96.45313 29.85666, -96.45292 29.85671, -96.45287 29.85678, -96.45279 29.85691, -96.45267 29.85698, -96.45249 29.85698, -96.45235 29.85695, -96.45221 29.85687, -96.45208 29.85678, -96.45188 29.85661, -96.45174 29.85654, -96.45159 29.85650, -96.45138 29.85651, -96.45127 29.85657, -96.45115 29.85669, -96.45110 29.85682, -96.45106 29.85697, -96.45096 29.85697, -96.45092 29.85693, -96.45081 29.85676, -96.45071 29.85668, -96.45062 29.85664, -96.45050 29.85661, -96.45027 29.85660, -96.44983 29.85660, -96.44965 29.85657, -96.44947 29.85649, -96.44925 29.85632, -96.44915 29.85629, -96.44900 29.85631, -96.44871 29.85630, -96.44854 29.85636, -96.44851 29.85634, -96.44837 29.85623, -96.44807 29.85607, -96.44786 29.85601, -96.44765 29.85597, -96.44758 29.85594, -96.44734 29.85577, -96.44720 29.85570, -96.44706 29.85565, -96.44669 29.85556, -96.44655 29.85545, -96.44645 29.85525, -96.44636 29.85497, -96.44630 29.85491, -96.44620 29.85488, -96.44599 29.85487, -96.44579 29.85493, -96.44567 29.85493, -96.44551 29.85491, -96.44524 29.85488, -96.44521 29.85499, -96.44517 29.85523, -96.44513 29.85531, -96.44501 29.85547, -96.44481 29.85564, -96.44462 29.85573, -96.44451 29.85576, -96.44436 29.85577, -96.44419 29.85574, -96.44402 29.85568, -96.44395 29.85564, -96.44384 29.85557, -96.44374 29.85554, -96.44368 29.85553, -96.44346 29.85553, -96.44337 29.85548, -96.44334 29.85539, -96.44337 29.85532, -96.44346 29.85516, -96.44347 29.85505, -96.44344 29.85501, -96.44332 29.85485, -96.44331 29.85456, -96.44346 29.85467, -96.44370 29.85484, -96.44370 29.85484, -96.44384 29.85481, -96.44402 29.85477, -96.44414 29.85474, -96.44453 29.85448, -96.44499 29.85388, -96.44499 29.85388, -96.44534 29.85384, -96.44534 29.85384, -96.44590 29.85421, -96.44590 29.85421, -96.44630 29.85482, -96.44638 29.85489, -96.44638 29.85489, -96.44656 29.85504, -96.44656 29.85504, -96.44794 29.85544, -96.44809 29.85557, -96.44837 29.85573, -96.44859 29.85580, -96.44881 29.85584, -96.44906 29.85581, -96.44928 29.85578, -96.44952 29.85584, -96.44967 29.85593, -96.44988 29.85610, -96.45003 29.85615, -96.45041 29.85616, -96.45058 29.85614, -96.45088 29.85608, -96.45103 29.85605, -96.45114 29.85602, -96.45135 29.85597, -96.45155 29.85591, -96.45170 29.85587, -96.45188 29.85582, -96.45207 29.85573, -96.45213 29.85566, -96.45213 29.85566, -96.45221 29.85565, -96.45237 29.85563, -96.45383 29.85560, -96.45386 29.85558, -96.45395 29.85554, -96.45408 29.85529, -96.45414 29.85519, -96.45426 29.85496, -96.45443 29.85478, -96.45455 29.85465, -96.45470 29.85455, -96.45481 29.85448, -96.45490 29.85443, -96.45490 29.85443, -96.45513 29.85438, -96.45525 29.85435, -96.45529 29.85434, -96.45529 29.85434, -96.45635 29.85438, -96.45641 29.85440, -96.45664 29.85448, -96.45779 29.85485, -96.45779 29.85485, -96.45792 29.85483, -96.45795 29.85482, -96.45827 29.85477, -96.45910 29.85463, -96.45923 29.85461, -96.45934 29.85460, -96.45967 29.85456, -96.45977 29.85455, -96.45977 29.85455, -96.45977 29.85455, -96.45998 29.85466, -96.46039 29.85536, -96.46056 29.85566, -96.46086 29.85618, -96.46322 29.85838, -96.46365 29.85877, -96.46365 29.85877, -96.46373 29.85893, -96.46373 29.85893, -96.46373 29.85893, -96.46381 29.85910, -96.46384 29.85923, -96.46402 29.86001, -96.46402 29.86001, -96.46432 29.86040, -96.46456 29.86050, -96.46481 29.86059, -96.46703 29.86057, -96.46719 29.86060, -96.46777 29.86069, -96.46777 29.86069, -96.47021 29.86246, -96.47092 29.86340, -96.47177 29.86428, -96.47177 29.86428, -96.47214 29.86467, -96.47229 29.86495, -96.47233 29.86501, -96.47233 29.86501, -96.47244 29.86537, -96.47231 29.86527, -96.47214 29.86519, -96.47206 29.86517, -96.47180 29.86517, -96.47168 29.86515, -96.47146 29.86515, -96.47141 29.86501, -96.47128 29.86463, -96.47118 29.86446, -96.47104 29.86427, -96.47075 29.86396, -96.47054 29.86379, -96.47034 29.86366, -96.46981 29.86341, -96.46967 29.86333, -96.46961 29.86326, -96.46948 29.86308, -96.46938 29.86302, -96.46917 29.86292, -96.46898 29.86275, -96.46887 29.86255, -96.46886 29.86247, -96.46882 29.86220, -96.46875 29.86211, -96.46863 29.86205, -96.46857 29.86203, -96.46829 29.86196, -96.46813 29.86183, -96.46793 29.86164, -96.46780 29.86155, -96.46778 29.86151, -96.46777 29.86128, -96.46769 29.86118))  AV
10  POLYGON ((-96.42751 29.84184, -96.42716 29.84154, -96.42699 29.84142, -96.42690 29.84139, -96.42665 29.84131, -96.42653 29.84120, -96.42647 29.84106, -96.42642 29.84090, -96.42641 29.84082, -96.42635 29.84055, -96.42627 29.84034, -96.42617 29.84018, -96.42600 29.83999, -96.42582 29.83980, -96.42551 29.83951, -96.42530 29.83929, -96.42505 29.83897, -96.42487 29.83867, -96.42478 29.83842, -96.42473 29.83817, -96.42471 29.83774, -96.42468 29.83762, -96.42462 29.83753, -96.42453 29.83745, -96.42443 29.83738, -96.42431 29.83735, -96.42396 29.83728, -96.42387 29.83724, -96.42374 29.83715, -96.42356 29.83694, -96.42347 29.83679, -96.42342 29.83666, -96.42338 29.83645, -96.42338 29.83625, -96.42343 29.83627, -96.42363 29.83634, -96.42363 29.83634, -96.42378 29.83635, -96.42389 29.83635, -96.42391 29.83635, -96.42399 29.83631, -96.42429 29.83619, -96.42439 29.83615, -96.42449 29.83615, -96.42455 29.83615, -96.42455 29.83615, -96.42462 29.83621, -96.42472 29.83628, -96.42480 29.83653, -96.42486 29.83670, -96.42486 29.83670, -96.42476 29.83771, -96.42480 29.83794, -96.42484 29.83821, -96.42484 29.83821, -96.42504 29.83864, -96.42504 29.83864, -96.42507 29.83870, -96.42507 29.83871, -96.42507 29.83871, -96.42558 29.83927, -96.42607 29.83961, -96.42665 29.84003, -96.42720 29.84028, -96.42798 29.84040, -96.42798 29.84040, -96.42817 29.84043, -96.42865 29.84050, -96.43037 29.84076, -96.43089 29.84084, -96.43125 29.84090, -96.43130 29.84090, -96.43231 29.84090, -96.43305 29.84090, -96.43329 29.84097, -96.43329 29.84097, -96.43336 29.84100, -96.43357 29.84106, -96.43396 29.84133, -96.43415 29.84146, -96.43434 29.84169, -96.43434 29.84169, -96.43436 29.84178, -96.43437 29.84184, -96.43441 29.84203, -96.43437 29.84225, -96.43436 29.84226, -96.43436 29.84227, -96.43436 29.84227, -96.43434 29.84221, -96.43425 29.84202, -96.43415 29.84188, -96.43402 29.84182, -96.43390 29.84179, -96.43376 29.84178, -96.43359 29.84180, -96.43334 29.84187, -96.43320 29.84192, -96.43300 29.84204, -96.43279 29.84218, -96.43266 29.84229, -96.43265 29.84230, -96.43261 29.84233, -96.43246 29.84248, -96.43241 29.84254, -96.43232 29.84266, -96.43223 29.84279, -96.43220 29.84300, -96.43212 29.84307, -96.43184 29.84316, -96.43173 29.84320, -96.43165 29.84324, -96.43146 29.84333, -96.43125 29.84351, -96.43118 29.84351, -96.43112 29.84348, -96.43100 29.84335, -96.43089 29.84323, -96.43067 29.84300, -96.43045 29.84284, -96.43036 29.84279, -96.43020 29.84270, -96.42996 29.84259, -96.42973 29.84250, -96.42936 29.84232, -96.42911 29.84222, -96.42892 29.84217, -96.42891 29.84217, -96.42884 29.84216, -96.42871 29.84214, -96.42839 29.84209, -96.42790 29.84205, -96.42767 29.84195, -96.42751 29.84184))  AV
```

Checking that these have the same CRS

```
points.crs
<Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4269>
Name: NAD83
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
- Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- name: North America - NAD83
- bounds: (167.65, 14.92, -47.74, 86.46)
Datum: North American Datum 1983
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich

shape3.crs

<Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4269>
Name: NAD83
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
- Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- name: North America - NAD83
- bounds: (167.65, 14.92, -47.74, 86.46)
Datum: North American Datum 1983
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

Computing distance:

```
dist_point_pol = points.boundary.distance(shape3.geometry)

UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'distance' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation.
```

I reprojected using

```
points2 = points.to_crs(epsg=3857)
shape4 = shape3.to_crs(epsg=3857)

dist_point_pol2 = points2.boundary.distance(shape4.geometry)
UserWarning: The indices of the two GeoSeries are different.
  warn("The indices of the two GeoSeries are different.")
```

I thought something such as `.reset_index()` would fix this but this is not the case. In the end, I either get things that doesn't make sense or just `NaN`.

I may have gotten the wrong function. I actually need something that computes the distance from each point to the nearest flood zone (so, not aligned as `.distance` would assume but adding `align=False` gives me an error message as if `align` is not an expected input) and from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/375512/84607) answer I thought `.boundary.distance()` was the correct one, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Can you export `points.head()` and `shape3.head()` to csv to have fully polygons, please?

Comment: Does the edit (data in a code block) help? If not, I'll figure out how to post the csv. Thanks.

Comment: Now I have the same data as you and the same errors :-).

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, we are using the [`nearest_points`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#nearest-points) function of [`shapely`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html).

1. Prepare some data:

```
df1 = points.to_crs(epsg=3857)
df2 = shape3.to_crs(epsg=3857)

# Extract point from you GeoDataFrame
point = df1.geometry

# Compute centroid of your area
centroid = df2.centroid

# Create unary union from centroid of area
centroids = unary_union(centroid)
```

```
>>> point.to_wkt()
0    POINT (-10608848.77333559 3487304.924649447)
1    POINT (-10634180.63666051 3463757.741176611)
2    POINT (-10585439.39761668 3476544.997885468)
3     POINT (-10591535.25293251 3447012.74414724)
4    POINT (-10655540.62055392 3480120.372628092)
dtype: object

>>> centroid.to_wkt()
2     POINT (-10706645.37489606 3477794.283230069)
3       POINT (-10703147.61430024 3510692.1568683)
5     POINT (-10697256.38062128 3458615.305393973)
8     POINT (-10737620.52149788 3485241.842837139)
10      POINT (-10734474.301016 3483131.295266777)
dtype: object

>>> centroids.to_wkt()
'MULTIPOINT (-10737620.5214978829026222 3485241.8428371394984424, 
             -10734474.3010160010308027 3483131.2952667772769928, 
             -10706645.3748960644006729 3477794.2832300686277449, 
             -10703147.6143002416938543 3510692.1568683004006743, 
             -10697256.3806212786585093 3458615.3053939728997648)'
```

2. Compute distance between each `point` and `centroids`

```
out = point.apply(lambda p: centroid == nearest_points(p, centroids)[1])
```

`nearest_points` returns a tuple, in this case:

- `[0]` → `POINT` p
- `[1]` → the nearest `POINT` in `MULTIPOINT`

It only remains to find the `POINT[1]` among the list of centroid, so we have the following crosstab:

```
>>> out
      2      3     5      8      10
0  False  False  True  False  False
1  False  False  True  False  False
2  False  False  True  False  False
3  False  False  True  False  False
4  False  False  True  False  False

>>> out.idxmax(axis="columns")
0    5
1    5
2    5
3    5
4    5
dtype: int64
```

**One-liner**

```
>>> df1.apply(lambda p: df2.centroid == \
                        nearest_points(p.geometry, df2.centroid.unary_union)[1],
              axis="columns").idxmax(axis="columns")
0    5
1    5
2    5
3    5
4    5
dtype: int64
```

**Edit**: another method

```
df1 = points.to_crs(epsg=3857)
df2 = shape3.to_crs(epsg=3857)

point = df1.geometry
polygon = df2.geometry

out = point.apply(lambda p: polygon.distance(p))
```

```
>>> out
              2              3              5              8              10
0   98131.524964   96824.778253   92693.462319  127194.722351  125043.444702
1   73719.669946   83033.617116   63047.492025  104004.590418  101372.084859
2  121097.679806  122221.621814  113001.243242  150810.634442  148482.376394
3  119072.273823  128120.650093  106140.417246  149361.810890  146630.045936
4   51036.728734   56191.958501   46675.287835   80619.485414   78297.679404

>>> out.idxmin(axis="columns")
0    5
1    5
2    5
3    5
4    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer but 1) I'm having trouble replicating it and 2) I have a question. On 1), ```point.to_wkt()``` and ```centroid.to_wkt()``` result in: ```'GeoSeries' object has no attribute 'to_wkt'```. ```centroids.to_wkt()``` works. The rest is the same as yours. On 2) doesn't this identify the closest centroid, but not the distance? If a centroid changes because the boundary that is further away from a point changes while the nearest boundary to the point doesn't, shouldn't the distance to the nearest polygon remain the same? How is this captured here? Thanks.

Comment: 1) Curious, maybe we have not the same version (`geopandas`: 0.9.0, `shapely`: 1.7.1.

Comment: 2) I know you're right, centroid is an approximation and it's easier to measure distance between points rather than between points and polygons. It was an example to introduce `nearest_points`

Comment: It certainly helped me in getting an approximated distance. Now I need to figure out how to do it to a boundary. Thanks.